# How to search keyword in DES encrypted fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, des

I encrypted some fields like name and mobile then stored them in SQL Server, now I have to search the fields.

For example: `select * from X_Table where Name Like 'aaa'`.

The Name field is encrypted and the `aaa` unencrypted. How should I do this?

Comment: Encrypt the constant for the comparison.

Comment: It should not work. Because i need the fuzzy match, not the exact match.

Comment: Then you need to decrypt every cell in that column. That's probably going to be very costly. Why did you encrypt that column in the first place?

Comment: This is customer demand. I think i should decrypt every cell in that column.

Comment: @zjhui . . . `like 'aaa'` isn't really a fuzzy match, unless you are considering case as "fuzzy".  You can fix that by putting all values in a constant case before encoding them.